# DNS server Application Layer

Tags: networking, dns, server

what will happen if all DNS server in the world crash simultaneously? how it will change ability to use internet

Answer (score 0):

First of all let me to explain why it is an unlikely event that "All the DNS" crash at the same time.

Each domain name is resolved by multiple name servers. Many registrars demand that these name servers belong to different network regions, so that if one outage happens, the domain name still can be resolved.

The response of an authoritative DNS is also cached on every level. There is a TTL (time-to-live) entry in host records that tells the sub-level ISP routers to "remember" the result for the set period of time. This is why changing the IP address of a domain record takes time to "propagate".

Having said that, catastrophic failures do occur. In 2013, the GoDaddy DNS servers systematically failed, rendering thousands if not tens of thousands of websites unreachable. Name resolution is not just for browsing; it is also used between machines, such as remote database access, time server, automated file transfer, etc. Any "connection by name" service will fail.

If you just want to access a website during such event, and that you know the IP address of the web server, you could edit the "hosts" file to manually resolve the name on your machine. Then again, when all the DNS servers fail at the same time, there's something deeply wrong with the entire Internet infrastructure, and your browsing may be affected by other factors.

Answer (score 0):

DNS is a core service. While, theoretically, things could continue to work by using IP addresses, in reality, without DNS, most of the services on the internet would crash and burn.

Schien is correct tho, DNS is a very well-designed protocol and structure and, for the most part, decently implemented across the internet. A complete and total failure has an infinitesimal probability.